# broken img link when trying to display an image stored in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, blob

I have seen similar questions here on stack overflow but I didn't understand the answers so I thought, I'd post the question myself and correspond with any of the helpful programmers. I'm trying to display an image which is stored in a database and I am getting a broken image link. I have two php files as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload an image</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="image_practice.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Image: <input type="file" name="image"> <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
    <?php
if (function_exists('hex2bin') !== true)
    {
        function hex2bin($data)
        {
            return pack("H*", $data);
        }
    }
        //file properties
        $file= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        if (!isset($file))
            echo "Please select an image";
        else{
            $image = bin2hex(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image = hex2bin($image['Image']);
            if ($image_size==FALSE)
                echo "That's not an image";
            else {
                if(!$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ImageDetails VALUES('','$image_name','$image')"))
                    echo "Problem Uploading image.";
                else {
                  $lastid= mysql_insert_id();
                  echo "Image Uploaded.<p />Your Image:<p \><img src='GetImage_prac.php?id=$lastid'>";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and then another php file which displays the image as follows:

```
<?php
  if (function_exists('hex2bin') !== true)
{
    function hex2bin($data)
    {
        return pack("H*", $data);
    }
}$id=addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);
  $image= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ImageDetails WHERE id=$id");
  $image= mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
  $image= $image['Image'];
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $image;
?>
```

I don't understand why the image isn't displaying. Can anyone help? I think the table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ImageDetails2
(
ImageId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
Image BLOB,
PRIMARY KEY(ImageId)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the culprit is `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

---

Also, bare in mind that the `BLOB` MySQL data type has a limit of 64KB, which, because of the base64 encoding inflation, represents a true file limit of ~48KB - if you try to upload a bigger file it'll get truncated and it will display a corrupted file afterwards (= display nothing).

---

Okay, I re-did your whole code, the problem was the query in the display script:

```
SELECT * FROM ImageDetails WHERE id=$id
```

Should be:

```
SELECT * FROM ImageDetails WHERE ImageId=$id
```

Anyway, here it is, all fixed and improved. It **has to** work now:

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload an image</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="image_practice.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="image">Image:</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
        </form>
        <?php

        if ((strcasecmp('POST', $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 0) && (isset($_FILES) === true))
        {
            if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) != false)
            {
                $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                $image_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);

                $image = base64_encode($image); 

                if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO ImageDetails VALUES ('', '$image_name', '$image');") !== false)
                {
                    echo 'Image Uploaded.<p />Your Image:<p \><img src="GetImage_prac.php?id=' . mysql_insert_id() . '">';
                }

                else
                {
                    echo "Problem Uploading image.";
                }
            }

            else
            {
                echo "That's not an image.";
            }
        }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php

// connect to MySQL here

if (array_key_exists('id', $_REQUEST) === true)
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ImageDetails WHERE ImageId = " . intval($_REQUEST['id']) . " LIMIT 1;"); # you had "WHERE id" here!
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    if ($result !== false)
    {
        $image = $result['Image'];

        $image = base64_decode($image);
    }
}

if (isset($image) === true)
{
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); echo $image;
}

else # display a 1x1 spacer GIF as fallback
{
    $image = base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==');

    header('Content-type: image/gif'); echo $image;
}

?>
```

Comment: @ Alix Axel that unfortunately hasn't fixed it!

Comment: @ Alix Axel still didn't change anything

Comment: @user2363025: I copied `hex2bin` from somewhere and I forgot to change a variable. Try again please. If it doesn't work, post the updated code you're using to insert and display, as well as the table definition (`SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`).

Comment: @ Alix Axel please forgivee me for my lack of knowledge on the subject. But what variable do I need to change?

Comment: @user2363025: The `hex2bin` function snippet.

Comment: I still don't understand what variable you want me to change or what to change it to? :/ Really sorry for the stupid questions. Oh I've only just seen the change to H*!

Comment: @user2363025: The code I posted... Just copy it again and replace the whole thing.

Comment: @user2363025: The change actually was one occurrence of `$hex_string` to `$data`.

Comment: Ok I changed it. Still doesn't work. I got the following error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'Image' in /home/roseanne/public_html/image_practice.php on line 34 Warning: hex2bin(): Hexadecimal input string must have an even length in /home/roseanne/public_html/image_practice.php on line 34 Notice: Undefined variable: image_size in /home/roseanne/public_html/image_practice.php on line 36 That's not an image

Comment: @user2363025: You're doing something wrong. Let me quickly write the whole code for you.

Comment: Frankly speaking, wasting space by a factor of two can't be a good solution for solving this problem.

Comment: @Adder: What do you mean by wasting space by a factor of two?

Comment: @Adder: Ah, you mean the bin to hex conversion... I thought you're referring to the BLOB requirements. Yeah, I think I saw a solution to safely store BLOBs directly but I can't remember anymore.

Comment: @ Alix Axel Thanks so much for all your help. I uploaded your code to my server and it still has the broken image??

Comment: @Alix I thought of using hex as encoding as you said initially but you use base 64 now, which has 25% waste only (2 bits out of 8). Still, the same argument applies: it wastes space.

Comment: @Adder: Yeah, I was reading the manual but still can't find it. I switched to base64 mainly because the hex2bin function I copied was buggy.

Comment: @user2363025: Are you sure you copied both files in my gist correctly? The code you just updated in your question is totally wrong, you use the wrong functions in the wrong places...

Comment: @Alix Axel I copied and pasted them.

Comment: @user2363025: I updated my answer. Please copy both files again (just to make sure). Also, is the jpeg file you're trying to upload bigger than 64KB?

Comment: @Alix Axel Ok so I reuploaded your updated answer. Still get the broken image and the image is 13.2 KiB

Comment: @Alix Axel Another error which I haven't mentioned is that when I first open the display.php page I get the following message (underneath the buttons to upload the image). Notice: Undefined index: image in /home/roseanne/public_html/uploadPic.php on line 11

Comment: The key in an array is case sensitive: Probably "Image" not "image".

Comment: @user2363025: I wanted to invite you to chat, even upvoted all of you questions so you would have enough reputation but apparently SO is keeping your 9 points in cache and won't let me do it...

Comment: @ Adder 'image' is what I have used in my form. With a small i. I changed it to the Image just for a test and I still got the error

Comment: @user2363025: Anyway... Before you posted an error that mentioned line 69! We don't have that many lines here, please don't mix bugs. That happens, because your first request to `uploadPic.php` is a GET one, has no form submission hence $_FILES isn't populated and you get the warning. You need to do something like `if (isset($_FILES))` before.

Comment: @Alix Axel I've just got a notification that I could chat. Can you invite me again?

Comment: @user2363025: SO isn't giving me the option to invite you now... Can you invite me?

Comment: @Alix Axel I've just noticed that in your updated answer the action in the form was my other file image_prac.php so I changed that to the new one I created with your code and called it Upload.php. Now I am not getting the broken image pic but I am getting the error: Problem uploading image

Comment: @user2363025: Lets talk in the chat please, this is taking way too long and it's getting pretty confusing with all the changes I don't know you did.

Comment: @Alix Axel Sorry I just clicked your link but I don't think I can talk in it. There is no space for me to write text anywhere!

Comment: @Alix Axel maybe I won't get to talk until tomorrow. You hardly can chat then?

Comment: @Alix Axel OK I have to leave work now because they are locking up and I won't have wifi but I hope you could talk tomorrow and I DO appreciate all the help. I've only just started an internship and I'm not able to do this and it sucks :/

Comment: @user2363025: Nevermind, had to rewrite the whole thing but I found the bug. Check the update on my answer for the solution.

Comment: @Alix Axel Getting a problem uploading image problem now! This has turned into such a mess, and it works perfectly for someone doing it on youtube!

Comment: @user2363025: Can you tell me what the exact problem is?

Comment: @ Alix Axel I wrote it in the chat link you put up yesterday :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot at something that may cause the error, but it can be an other:

Check that there is no unicode BOM at the start of the php file that outputs the image.

To do this (and even more), save the image when the browser presents the error, rename it to text, or look at it using a hex editor and compare that with the initial image.

A BOM looks like this in a non-unicode (hex-)editor: ï»¿.

Comment: This is ruled out by the warning the OP got, but nice thinking, +1!

Comment: How does a warning about a bad hex encoding rule it out - he needs to make sure the image is not only stored correctly, but also displayed correctly, that is where the BOM might come in. He also will be able to see PHP warnings and errors in the downloaded (broken) image file.

Comment: It has been a long time since I made the mistake of saving PHP files with BOM, but back then (if I remember correctly) nothing was outputted (not even errors) - but then again, that might be due to the HTTP server.

Comment: Anyway, I'm feeling more inclined to the truncated contents theory right now (BLOB has a limit of only 64KB).

Comment: That is a good idea, too. He would have to use LONGBLOB then.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using chrome right click on the broken image and inspect the element and see what is wrong with the code.

Do you have the html for the img src inside the database rows? if so its a waste having it in there it should be in the php file and if you dont then thats your problem

Comment: @ Dan Hastings. In google chrome inspect element, it's the line <img src="GetImage_prac.php?id=12"> that has the error. In the database rows I have an actual blob file???

Comment: by the looks of it the data you have stored in the database for the image source is wrong. what you are doing is setting the source of the image as a php file. Im guessing that the php file is what you call and it will return the image with id 12? Why cant you store the actual file path in the db? eg /images/gallery/img.jpg then just insert that into the img src?

Comment: Another potential problem is that the image may not be image/jpeg it might be a better solution to get the mime type of the uploaded file and save that in the database as well.

Comment: @Dan Hastings Yes you are guessing right. But the images are stored in the database, when I go and browse the tables. But it's the displaying which isn't working. How can I store the file path in the db?

Comment: @ Orangepill I specifically used a jpeg for testing to see if that would work first, but it didn't. I get the broken image

Comment: @Orangepill: That is easily fixable.

Comment: its not possible to store an iimage in a db all you are doing is storing a string with the image path and in your case you are storing them in a way that they can never be called. A php page wont return a result to another php page (unless you use ajax) but you are over complicating things so much. I have done this a lot and i always store the string path of the image in the db.eg images/gallery/imgage1.jpg. then i query the db and insert the string inside img src. eg.<img src = '$image'/>.Once the server hands the page to the browser the src will read. <img src = 'images/gallery/image1.jpg'/>

Comment: @user2363025: To store the path in the DB, you just store the path in the DB! :P As in, you move `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` to a directory of your choice (use `move_uploaded_file()`) for that, you get it's path (`realpath()`) and INSERT that value in the DB. To display, you can either do what you're doing but using `$image = file_get_contents($pathToImageInDB);` or just point the browser directly to the image `$pathToImageInDB` (if it's in publicly available folder).

Comment: @DanHastings: "its not possible to store an iimage in a db" a image (or any other file) is nothing more than a collection of characters (aka strings) and "a php page wont return a result to another php page" yes it will, even without Ajax.

Comment: another option to insulate you against encoding issues in and out of the database is to run through base64_encode/base64_decode.

Comment: @ Dan Hastings I'm pretty sure you can. I was following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFZfJZ_WNC4 and it seemed to work for them!

Comment: @DanHastings: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html . Use BLOB data type for storing images

Comment: @Adder why do it though? there is an easier way and when storing images in the db they are going to take up a lot of space filling up the db much quicker than you normally would. keep your files on the web hosts drive so they can take up all the memory they like and then keep the dynamic details in the db. you want your queries to be as quick as possible. the page wont load til the query is done where as the page will load even if the images are still loading if you keep them with the php pages

Comment: @DanHastings: It's easier alright but there are valid reasons to do it - like preventing anyone with a direct URL from being served the image without some prior server-side checks for instance. And BLOBs are stored in disk by MySQL, so they don't eat memory and can't be indexable.